# Give css dynamically to elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, if-statement

I've got the following object:

```js
{
  "market": {
    "blue": {
      "walls": {
        "north": false,
        "east": false,
        "south": true,
        "west": true
      }
    },
    "green": {
      "walls": {
        "north": true,
        "east": true,
        "south": false,
        "west": false
      }
    },
    "orange": {
      "walls": {
        "north": true,
        "east": false,
        "south": true,
        "west": true
      }
    },
    "yellow": {
      "walls": {
        "north": false,
        "east": true,
        "south": true,
        "west": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate over market, then over blue, green, orange and yellow. And inside those colours I would like to iterate over the walls. If a certain key has value true, I would like to apply some CSS in the browser. 
However, when logging this JSON object in the browser, it doesn't show up as an array, i.e. the browser doesn't recognise the length of market, or blue or the other colours.

I've tried iterating over this object with (nested) for-loops, but it doesn't return anything. Is it even possible to iterate over said object, or am I stuck to writing 16 if-statements for each key/value pair?

This is how I iterate over the object:

```js
const response = {
  "market": {
    "blue": {
      "walls": {
        "north": false,
        "east": false,
        "south": true,
        "west": true
      }
    },
    "green": {
      "walls": {
        "north": true,
        "east": true,
        "south": false,
        "west": false
      }
    },
    "orange": {
      "walls": {
        "north": true,
        "east": false,
        "south": true,
        "west": true
      }
    },
    "yellow": {
      "walls": {
        "north": false,
        "east": true,
        "south": true,
        "west": false
      }
    }
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < response.market.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < response.market[i].walls.length; j++) {
    if (response.market[i].walls[0] === true) {
      response.market[i].walls[0].style.borderTop = "3px solid black";
    } else if (response.market[i].walls[1] === true) {
      response.market[i].walls[1].style.borderRight = "3px solid black";
    } else if (response.market[i].walls[2] === true) {
      response.market[i].walls[2].style.borderBottom = "3px solid black";
    } else if (response.market[i].walls[3] === true) {
      response.market[i].walls[3].style.borderLeft = "3px solid black";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well show your code and what you've tried so far ? I can already spot what's wrong but it'd be nice to see how you've approached the problem, codewise.

Comment: Are you doing that with JS, right?

Comment: @GerardoPerrucci don't solve his problem right away. Let's see what he has tried so far. Answer this question directly would be strongly against the community guidelines.

Comment: @ZombieChowder ok, I didn't know

Comment: @ZombieChowder I removed the answer

Comment: I've added my nested for-loops to my post, can't currently see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should be getting an error in your console regarding not being able to get the property `length` from `market` since it is not an array. Note that there is no such thing as a "JSON Array" or "JSON Object"; JSON is a text format. Once it's been parsed, it's just arrays and objects, just like any others.

Comment: Also, even if there were arrays here, the end result of, say, `response.market[i].walls[0]` would not be a DOM element, but rather a Boolean, which does not have a `style` property.

Comment: Logging the output of any index into the console just doesn't return anything, not even undefined. Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`markets` is an object so markets.length will return undefined.In order to iterate through through the objects keys and values we have `Object.keys(obj)` and `Object.values(obj)`.

```
Object.keys(response.market).forEach(paint =>{
   //iterating through "blue","green","orange","yellow"
    Object.keys(response.market[paint]["walls"]).forEach(wall =>{
       //iterating through north,east,south,west
        if(response.market[paint]["walls"][wall]==true){
            switch(wall){
                case "north": response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderTop"]="3px solid black";break;
                case "east":  response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderRight"]="3px solid black";break;
                case "south": response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderBottom"]="3px solid black";break;
                case "west":  response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderLeft"]="3px solid black";break;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

```js
let response = {"market": {"blue": {"walls": {"north": false,"east": false,"south": true,"west": true}},"green": {"walls": { "north": true, "east": true,"south": false,"west": false}},"orange": {"walls": { "north": true,"east": false, "south": true,"west": true}},"yellow": {"walls": {"north": false, "east": true, "south": true,"west": false}}}};
Object.keys(response.market).forEach(paint => {
    Object.keys(response.market[paint]["walls"]).forEach(wall => {
        if (response.market[paint]["walls"][wall] == true) {
            switch (wall) {
                case "north":response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderTop"] = "3px solid black";break;
                case "east":response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderRight"] = "3px solid black";break;
                case "south":response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderBottom"] = "3px solid black";break;
                case "west":response.market[paint]["walls"]["borderLeft"] = "3px solid black"; break;
            }
        }
    })
});
console.log(response.market);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ah I see now, in regard to the Object! Thank you very much